# The program keeps executing for a long time

Tags: vba, excel

I have three Sheets, sheet1 , sheet2 and sheet3.

I am trying to copy the sheet 1, column N and F in sheet3.

Then,  With this ID,I look into column A and see if they are matching, 
If so then I copy the Matched ID to sheet3.

I am using below code, for this reason.

the code was working fine till now. But I update my sheet2 today morning, and due to some reason, the code is Keep on executing for a Long time and still i am not able to get the Output, I am unable to figure out the reason for this.

I tried to debug and the line below was highlighted.

> If Not rng Is Nothing Then

In Addition, I am using an button in the worksheet and calling the functions like

> call thisworkbook.lookup

similarly i have 6 other functions, attached to this button.

Here is the complete code. Could someone help me to figure out what is the reason for this .

```
Sub lookup()
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim Totalcolumns As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim i As Long
'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
Sheets("S1").Select
totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Totalcolumns = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'TotalRows = 441
'Totalcolumns = 392
Range("N5:N" & totalrows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("s3").Range("E5")
Range("F5:F" & totalrows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("s3").Range("H5")
'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("s3").Select
For i = 5 To totalrows
'Search for the value on sheet2
Set rng = Sheets("s2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
Cells(i, 9).Value = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
Cells(i, 12).Value = rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
Cells(i, 14).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions: Add "Thisworkbook" as a qualifier ahead of "Sheets" where you select the various sheet names.  This will make certain that its not trying to work with the ActriveWorkbook (it shouldn't...)  Does the worksheet have lots of formulas?  You could try:  `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the start, and `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end.  You can also try `application.screenupdating = false' at the start, and 'application.screenupdating=true' at the end.  Those things speed up vba routines on very large spreadsheets that take lots of time to calculate.

Comment: @ainwood ya, what are the suggestions ?

Comment: Looks like you could replace the VBA with a couple of VLOOKUP formulas, have you considered that?

Comment: @jkpieterse ya, i know that, but i would like to have them in VBA.

Comment: @ainwood I tried the ways you suggested me, the Problem is due to some reason, i am not able to Exit the if Loop. Also, on a small note, i have 118 rows in sht1 and sht2 has 950 rows. does this affect anyway ?

Comment: @ainwood , I notice the Problem in if Loop, when i debuged the code line by line, even after matching is done completely, the if Loop was Keep on running that it dint hit the end Sub Statement.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this?  `Set rng = Sheets("s2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then`??  You are setting the range, and then checking that the range is set (it should never be 'nothing').  Are you actually trying to see if it has a certain value?

Comment: I suspect the used range is your problem. Try hitting control+end on sheet S1, I expect Excel will take you to a very large row number.

Comment: @jkpieterse ya, you are correct, ist taking me to large row number

Comment: @ainwood it Looks into the e column of sht3, with this id, it Looks into sheet2, if anything is found then it paste into the Destination sheet.

Comment: @jkpieterse how do i overcome this issue? could you suggest me

Comment: Delete all rows past the last one that in your opinion is the real last used row. Then save the file

Comment: @jkpieterse , you mean to tell, i Need to delete the rows in my sheet1 and paste them again  ?

Comment: @jkpieterse it dint help me

Comment: @jkpieterse could you suggest me someother solution. The error still exist

Comment: No. I mean: 1. Find the last row in your spreadsheet S1 that contains data. 2. select the cell below that row. 3. Press control+shift+End on your keyboard. 4. Right-click in that range and select Delete. 5. Choose Delete Entire rows. 6. Save file

Comment: @jkpieterse it is solved :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the UserdRange of the worksheet S1 being way beyond its true size.
Problem solved by:

1. Find the last row in your spreadsheet S1 that contains data.
2. select the cell below that row.
3. Press control+shift+End on your keyboard.
4. Right-click in that range and select Delete.
5. Choose Delete Entire rows.
6. Save file